# Blazor WebAssembly - GetAuthenticationStateAsync() not called on page refresh

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have custom AuthenticationStateProvider in my Blazor WebAssembly app and it's not calling GetAuthenticationStateAsync method on page refresh so if user is logged in and then they manually refresh page ClaimsPrincipal is AuthenticationState is not populated so user can't be Authorized.
I'm using JWT which is saved in cookie for auth, and that cookie remains after page refresh, app just doesn't call GetAuthenticationStateAsync (which it should on page refresh if I learned blazor correctly).

Here's my custom AuthenticationStateProvider:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("APIClient");
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {

        //TODO get token from cookie
        var savedToken = "";

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) }, "apiauth"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
}
```

EDIT: It was calling GetAuthenticationStateAsync method the entire time, it was just confusing because I was in debugger and it never hit my breakpoint inside of that method, which is problem I saw other people (still not sure why is that).

Comment: Did this answer reply to your question? If it did, please confirm the answer for other user and to close this one. Thanks

Comment: For me, this is not the case, I have put a log line in GetAuthenticationStateAsync, and it doesn't get hit. So something is caching the state and not refreshing it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where you call `GetAuthenticationStateAsync`.
i.e. in *BlazorHero* project this call is present in the **MainLayout.razor**:

```html
</NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
        @(LoadDataAsync())
        <MudLayout RightToLeft="@_rightToLeft">
```

in **MainLayout.razor.cs**:

```
private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        var state = await _stateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = state.User;
        if (user == null) return;
```

so I think you need to check where it is called.

The **MainLayout** is rendered every time you load a page.

A better solution (cleaner) is to add this code in the `AfterRender` like:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await LoadDataAsync();
    }
}
```